# Where should I store js templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML templates inside of jQuery code, I use them for generating some new elements with JS. Currently, I keep them in the bottom of my page as

```
<script type="text/html" id="ID_to_refer_from_jQuery">...HTML code here...</script>
```

I feel it's not the best way to do this, because some of them are pretty big, is there a way to store string HTML templates outside of HTML file?

Comment: *"but I think it's a bad way"* ... why is that? How many do you have? There really isn't much information given here. See [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in another folder and call them in with AJAX. You don't want to have one huge file. Rather, leverage the organizational folder system to keep your project organized.

**Example Folder Structure**

```
/root
  index.html

  /templates
    navigation.html
    footer.html
    ...
```

**Loading Them In**

```
$("header").load("templates/navigation.html");
```

Comment: so I can use it like `var html_to_append = $.load("path_to_template.html");` ?

Comment: If you want to store it in a variable, see: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/load-a-div-from-an-external-file-into-a-variable

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the [HTML5 template feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template), but unfortunately it is not supported by Internet Explorer 10 or 11. Here is an example of it in use though:

```
<template id="simple">
    <style>
        span { color: purple; }
    </style>

    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <span>Hello World!</span>

    <script>
        function boom(){
            alert("BOOM!");
        }
        boom();
    </script>
</template>
```

```
function addSimple(){
    // Grab our template
    var t = document.querySelector('template#simple').content;

    // Optional -- Modify template

    // Clone and add
    var clone = document.importNode(t, true);
    document.getElementById("simple-target").appendChild(clone);
}
```

([Source of this example](http://dannyrb.com/posts/the-template-tag-a-refresher/))

---

In the mean time the most common way I've seen is to put your HTML in a JavaScript variable like this:

```
var html = [
'<div>',
'    <h1>Example Domain</h1>',
'    <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this',
'    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>',
'    <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>',
'</div>'
].join('');
```

If you have a chunk of HTML, there is even [an online tool](http://htmltojavascript.com/) that will format it as a JavaScript variable automatically.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but I don't want to store a lot of strings inside js.
And template feature still stores inside html, I consider not to do it.

Comment: From your question I thought you were looking for a way to store your templates inside your HTML. What do you mean when you say template? Do you mean a small piece of HTML that gets reused over and over? Or do you mean like a template for a whole web page?

Comment: I have some content that is not loaded with page, I load it after if needed. For example, popup. And when I click the button - popup template is appended into some container